# nginx php-fpm keeps downloading files

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

vhost:

```
server {
        listen *:8080;

        location / {
                root   /var/www/default/pub;
                index index.php;

                # if file exists return it right away
                if (-f $request_filename) {
                        break;
                }

                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php$1 last;
                        break;
                }

        }
        # serve static files directly
         location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
         access_log off;
         expires max;
  }

  location ~* \.php$ {
    # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
}
```

http://192.168.135.128/index.php loads just fine...

http://192.168.135.128/public_/html/index.php downloads...

Comment: You listen on 8080 so neither of those URLs ever touch Nginx. Also when you do starting using Nginx PHP won't work at all due to some basic mistake. I highly suggest you read my primer to get an understanding of the Nginx configuration file: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/

Comment: i have varnish in front of nginx doing caching and it runs on port 80

Answer (score 1):

Your vhost work well(but port 8080):

```
# curl localhost:8080/public_/html/index.php
123
```

/var/www/default/pub/public_/html/index.php:

```
<?php
echo "123";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your location block that sends php files to fpm is outside of your server block (due to an extra '}' )....
So, of course, nginx is not going to pass the file to php-fpm but rather just serve it up as is, which is basically the symptom you are describing.

That said, there are some other issues too with your configuration, but unrelated to the problem at hand...

```
}

location ~* \.php$ {
```

remove that extra '}' above 'location' and see if that resolves the issue.